# Search HTML form - how to keep value selected from dropdown list after submit

Tags: forms, list, search, select

hi i need help with a search form, i use the $_Get method, the INPUT TEXT Remain after submission which is as i want but the the select List DON'T! Why what is wrong ?

```
`<form action="index.php" method="Get"  name="auctionForm" >

 <input name="keyword" value="<?php echo $_GET['keyword'] ?>" type=text >

  <select name="cat" value="<?php echo $_GET['cat'] ?>" title="Select a category for search" >


     <option value="8">Antiques</option>

     <option value="9">Art</option>

     <option value="">Baby</option>

     <option value="51">Books</option>


   </select>

   <input name="go" value="Search" type=submit />

 `
```

So as you can see i used the $_Get method, the INPUT TEXT Remain after submission but the the select List DON'T! Why what is wrong ?
please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check in php if the $_GET value is equal to the value of each option like this

```
<select name="cat" value="" title="Select a category for search" >

 <option value="8" <?php if ($_GET['cat']==8) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?> >Antiques</option>    
 <option value="9" <?php if ($_GET['cat']==9) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Art</option>    
 <option value="2" <?php if ($_GET['cat']==2) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Baby</option>   
 <option value="51" <?php if ($_GET['cat']==51) {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Books</option>

</select>
```